# Finding insecure content on the page

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

When Chrome accesses a page that has some insecure content on the page, it puts a slash through the https:// and says that that is the case. How can I find the content that is not secured without going through the page source code?

Comment: See also: [How can you tell exactly what insecure items are causing a browser to warn about mixed secure and insecure items?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3920206)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can bring up Developer Tools (CTRL + SHIFT + I) and go to Console tab. there you will have log entries such as:

```
The page at ... displayed insecure content from ...
```

Comment: There is nothing listed... (I am showing all content). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of insecure content is it? It works for me with external images and JavaScript.

Comment: That is is what I am trying to find out...

Comment: Amazing! So simple, but I didn't notice it :)

Comment: Worked brilliantly for me. Was going nuts trying to figure out the source of the insecure content.